# Not able to install ExcelAddin.vsto file silently

Tags: vsto, alm

I am trying to create an unattended Silent install for HP ALM CLient Add for Citrix environment.

I am facing issues, when trying to suppress the "Install" customization window, which appears when we launch Excel. Couldn't able to suppress the window. Tried to install using below command but unsuccessful
VSTOInstaller.exe /Install \C:\Path\Exceladdin.vsto /Silent

I tried installing the certificate first by adding it to TRUSTEDPUBLISHERS then i tried to install, still no success.

Can someone help on this and anyone worked on this for Citrix environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use trust, the entire hierarchy for the public certificate must be trusted as well. Look at the Certification Path tab for the certificate you're using, and put the root certificate into the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities store, and anything between into the Intermediate Certification Authorities store. I know there's an MDSN page for this somewhere (or else I would not have this information), but I can't find it. It's probably somewhere under [Granting Trust to Office Solutions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb772086(v=vs.95)).

You could also use [inclusion lists](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb608607%28v=vs.95%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), or install it to the Program Files folder where Full Trust is automatically granted (because admin is required to put it there).

Comment: Thanks Chris. I will check this.